# How to make 'rake tmp:clear' also clear tmp/capybara?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rake, capybara

I notice that 'rake tmp:clear' does not clear tmp/capybara. Is there any way to make it do this by default, instead of implementing 'yet another rake task'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out to be as simple as creating a clear.rake file in lib/tasks, containing

```
require 'rake/clean'

CLEAN.include('tmp/capybara/*.html')
```

this is automatically picked up when executing

```
rake clear
```